# Web page crashing on web host but not on local host

Tags: javascript, php, sql, crash, connection

I have a php page which is working fine on my local host, but crashing on the webserver. I have checked with godaddy and all was fine on their end (not what I was hoping for...) and I am totally puzzled as to why it is failing to work properly on the server.

**About the page**

The page starts off by gathering post data from a form on a previous page.
It then checks to see if another form has been submitted. If the 2nd form has been submitted it runs an SQL INSERT, if not is carries on.
Then it uses the data from the first form to gather some data from 2 seperate tables in the same database. It then opens a table and some `<th>`'s. It then looks for information from a third table in the same database, and if data is found it will return that data to the table.
The data on the table is also a form where most fields are hidden. At the end of the table there is a submit button which posts the changeable fields in the form to a "Confirm and close" page (which works fine).

After the submit button there is a search field which allows users to search another (4th) table for data to add to the table/form above. Each search result is a form with a submit button labelled 'add'. When this form is submitted the data is posted to itself, and processed/added to the db and table.

This page crashed roughly every 5th time a user clicks add on a search result and can't be accessed for a couple of minutes. Does anyone know why?

**Added**

Oops, I forgot the error message:

Safari turns to a blank screen with the message "Safari cannot open the page because the network connection was lost". Other browsers are quite similar, but other websites and apps with internet required all work.

Comment: `"Does anyone know why?"` - We can't possibly know the cause of the error if you haven't provided us with any details about the error.

Comment: my apologies. Safari turns to a blank screen with the message "Safari cannot open the page because the network connection was lost". Other browsers are quite similar.

Comment: If the page is only crashing for a few minutes at a time are you sure your php script isn't overloading the server and using up all your ram allowance causing the server to be temporarily offline... I don't think people will be able to give a solid answer just from a description of the issue.

Comment: you're probably right there @NewToJS. I'm not really sure how to phrase the question better, but it sounds like you are with me :)
Also, I'm not sure if the php script is overloading the server to be honest. How can I check on that?

Comment: Log into your cpanel for that hosting. You should be able to see your hosting details / ram / cpu / disk space usage. One way of testing it to monitor those each time your php script is run. You say it will run 5 times.. run it, check, run it again and check. If you notice the usage is going up keep running it until it's almost full. If you manage to run it one more time and the site goes down then I think that would confirm the reason.

Comment: thanks heaps for your help. I'll try that now.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an issue a friend of mine had a couple of weeks ago. It turned out that the GoDaddy server was maxing out on memory. So the first thing I suggest is to login to your GoDaddy dashboard and check the memory of your instance. It should be easy to do that, if it's maxing out, you should see a red progress bar. If that's the case, you probably just found the problem. Then you either:

1. optimise your code
2. buy more memory
3. or move to another host provider

My friend went with #3 and he reported the problem was solved.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So you have basically repeated my comments but into your own little story... lol.

Comment: hey yeah sorry about that, just basically wanted to jump in I guess confirm your comment

Comment: That's fine, I  did post in comments and not as a answer so it's all good :)